# If you have the Sentinel feat, can you choose not to reduce a creature's speed to zero when you hit with an opportunity attack?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, movement, opportunity-attack

Assuming you have the Sentinel feat, can you choose to not reduce an opponent's speed to zero when you hit them with an opportunity attack?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## No; the speed reduction is not optional (assuming you hit)

The first benefit of the [Sentinel](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/feats/sentinel) feat (PHB, p. 169-170) says:

> When you hit a creature with an opportunity attack, the creature's speed becomes 0 for the rest of the turn.

It doesn't say you "can" reduce its speed to 0; it's simply stated as fact that if you hit with an opportunity attack, the target's speed becomes 0 - no exceptions.

So as it's worded, the speed reduction is mandatory if you hit with an opportunity attack.

Comment: I don't think you can even not use the feat. This might be good for another question.

Comment: @Mindwin: What do you mean?

Comment: if you have the sentinel feat, you set to zero the speed of any creature you hit with an AoO whether you want it or not. Just like a barbarian with heavy armor master would shove out 3 damage from a goblin's poker even if he wanted to take more damage (for whatever reason). I don't think you can opt to not use the feat's benefits once you have them. But as I said, this is for another question.

Comment: @Mindwin: I mean... That's exactly what this question is asking, and my answer states exactly what you've said in your comment. So it's not really "for another question" - that's exactly what this question and answer are about :P

Comment: @V2Blast While it's true that's a valid interpretation of what this question is about, this answer does not really address that topic at all.  Your answer assumes that feats are always on to make the statements it makes about the bullet point in the sentinel feat, but it doesn't support that assertion.  Nevertheless, your answer answers *another* reading of the question as asking about the particulars of that sentinel feat bullet point just fine, so it is a good answer to this question and it might be better to answer the broader question of whether you can not-use feats separately / elsewhere

Comment: @thedarkwanderer: Ah, I see what you mean. I suppose I "assume" that a feat's benefits are always on unless stated otherwise, because nothing in the rules contradicts that. Optional things are specifically described using wording suggesting they're optional (e.g. "you can..."). [Things do what they say they do.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/107637/33569) Related (closed) designer-reasons question: [Has a designer clarified whether using your class features are optional?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/129145/has-a-designer-clarified-whether-using-your-class-features-are-optional)

Comment: @V2Blast Oh, certainly, I'm not saying you are wrong! You just don't make that argument in *this* answer, but I think it's best to leave that sort of discussion about what, generally, you can choose not to use for another question or at least another answer, like I think Mindwin was trying to say.