# How do Mind Blank and Foresight interact?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

I'm preparing for a level 20 one shot and I'm trying to make a more support focused character. Two higher level support spells I'm eyeing are Mind Blank and Foresight, however the description of Mind Blank has me a bit concerned that I have to be careful with how they are cast together.

Mind Blank:

> Until the spell ends, one willing creature you touch is immune to
> psychic damage, any effect that would sense its emotions or read its
> thoughts, **divination spells**, and the charmed condition. The spell even
> foils wish spells and spells or effects of similar power used to
> affect the target's mind or to gain information about the target.

With Foresight being a divination spell it seems like they cannot be cast on the same character as Foresight is a divination spell which mind blank prohibits.

It also seems like if Mind Blanked character A was against Foresight character B, Foresight's effects would mostly fizzle against the Mind Blanked character.

Are these two interpretations of the interactions accurate, or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Apologies if you explained this in the question, I just want to clarify, are you asking about one person having both *mind blank* and *foresight* cast on them at the same time, or about two characters, each with one of the spells, interacting? Or both?

Comment: @ThomasMarkov both cases interest me as the two spells have interesting interactions in my mind. I can split it up if it's too broad as written though.

Comment: I think it's fine to be asking about both in one question. Just splitting that paragraph makes it clearer, I think.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Immunity to divination spells prevents *foresight* from buffing your ally.

Regrettably for your allies, the spell description here is perfectly general. Because "immune to... divination spells" is unqualified, even the ones that buff them are useless. [See also this similar question about resistance with answers stating that it is not optional.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/129139/are-your-resistances-optional)

It's not clear that this is RAI, though, so a lenient DM may permit *mind blank* to let divination buffs pass-through, while blocking enemies' divination.

Comment: Yeah, the intent seems to be that immunity means that other creatures cannot use divination to gain information about the target, but unfortunately it's not clearly worded that way.